# seq decimal separator

Tags: shell-script, terminal, floating-point, seq

Using a `seq` command with floating point numbers, my output comes with commas instead of dots as decimal separators, despite using dots in the input:

```
seq 0.1 0.3 1.3
0,1
0,4
0,7
1,0
1,3
```

I assumed this to be linked with the locale `LC_NUMERIC`, which is set to `de_DE.UTF-8`, however a change to `en_US.UTF-8` did not fix it and another system I have using the very same locale settings does return dots. Even explicitly defining a format via e.g. `-f %1.2` does not return dots but commas as decimal separators.

Where and how do I change this behaviour? How to ensure my script will error-free on any given system? Obviously any output will be unusable for further processing if not reprocessed via `tr` the like.

Using an English installation of Mint in German time zone and raspian on the other machine.

---

Edit: `locale` settings on the given machines:

The "comma" one:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The "dot" one:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Setting `LANGUAGE` does not affect the result.

Comment: The answer at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884934/seq-uses-comma-as-decimal-separator) does not seem to help and when `ssh`ing into either machine the behaviour is as the server defines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To exclude errors in the locales themselves, I (re)generated both `de_DE.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` via

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and now `seq` behaviour seems to be dependent on `LC_NUMERIC` **AND** `LANG`.

If `LC_NUMERIC` is unset/empty, `LANG` defines the bahaviour otherwise toggling `LC_NUMERIC` between`de_DE.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` switches between commas and dots, respectively.

---

**Specific dangers**

In the very case of setting a wrong/inexistent value for `LANG` and a non-dot-based `locale`, behaviour might be mixed in some special cases, e.g.

```
LANG=en_US
#it should be en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8

seq 0.1 0.2 1.3
0.1
0.3
0.5
0.7
0.9
1.1
1,3
```

It does not appear for `seq 0.1 0.2 1.4` but also for `seq 0.1 0.2 1.9` - very odd and IMHO very dangerous behaviour. So be careful with the portability of `seq` or define locales for any script.

Wildly guessing, this seems to be related to some manual change in specific cases (see: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-09/msg00192.html)

---

UPDATE:

The maintainers' suggestion to avoid any errors due to localized output formats is to define the locale in the script itself ( `LC_NUMERIC=C` ). Changing this behaviour is not planned. (See linked thread with patch below)

The problem with mixed dot and comma output due to bad locale settings has been recognised as a bug and already patched by the maintainers:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2019-02/msg00002.html

Comment: Die you Report a bug for it?

Comment: @eckes Yes, patch already available, see updated answer.